# Can vote to close have the option of migrating to Christianity.SE?

Tags: discussion, support

[This question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/134/should-christians-get-tattoos-or-avoid-them-biblically) seems more appropriate for Christianity.SE than Biblical Hermeneutics.  This site is likely to continue to get questions that are more appropriate there.  Can the vote to close be updated to give the option of migrating to Christianity.SE?

Is private beta may be too early to add that option?  Does it matter that Christianity.SE is still in beta too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This generally doesn't happen in beta: beta is the time for sites to define what they are without external influences like migration paths. In fact, I don't think it's *ever* happened.

Private beta is certainly too early to start migrating things: we just started asking questions about what's on-topic and what isn't here on meta.

But later on, if a question needs to be migrated, flag it for moderator review: they can migrate it to any site on the network regardless of migration paths set up.

Comment: There's been at least one migration from [Philosophy.SE] to [Christianity.SE] (both in beta) and from [Christianity.SE] to [English.SE].

Comment: (I might not understand what you mean by *migration path*)

Comment: @dancek If migration paths are set up for a site, when you vote to close a question as "off topic", you get a new dialog that asks you whether or not it should be migrated to one of the preset migration paths. These don't get set up until after the site graduates from beta. Diamond moderators can migrate a question to any site whether or not there are migration paths set up: any migrations from Philosophy or Christianity were done by a moderator, not through the use of migration paths ([example](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3812?noredirect=1)).